# Why is "pen" of "submarine pen" not in the dictionary?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

I saw this word a long time ago while playing red alert https://cnc.fandom.com/wiki/Submarine_pen_(Red_Alert_1) Since then i had forgotten about it, until a watched a youtube video on u-boats https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omn6VK64t9Q Wikipedia has it too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_pen "pen" seems to be a separate word but i could not find any definitions online that refer to something with ships. Could someone give a definition and explain why it isn't in the dictionary?

Comment: Which dictionary did you look at? [M-W is usually pretty good](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pen)

Comment: It's also given by AHD, Collins, RHK Webster's, Lexico. And, though I can't check at the moment, it will be in OED, the only possible claimant to the title 'the dictionary'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Merriam Webster online dictionary the definition of pen includes;

> *Noun* 3: a protected dock or slip for a submarine

Thanks for your question which has educated me on the use of the word.